# How to map users from Token Server using OpenId Connect

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identityserver4

It seems like no one can answer this question it shouldn't be that difficult I just can't find the proper documentation.  How can I map Users From IdentityServer4, which implement Oauth and OpenIdConnect, to my web api.

I can send my Authorization Request like so:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.onload = function () {
    log(xhr.status, JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
}
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + user.access_token);
xhr.send();
```

This only send the AccessToken,  I need to send the SubjectId, which is contained in the I'm assuming is contained in the `user.id_token` or perhaps the profile.

Comment: Does putting the SubjectId in the `access_token` work for you?

Comment: @user1336 that would work but how can I do that

Comment: If your client application requests the `profile` scope, it should contain the`Sub` claim.

Comment: Every token will always contain the sub claim if a user was involved.